# How to create a boolean method with no parameters - Java

Tags: java, parameter-passing

```
columnsAreValid(int[][] array){
    return true;
rowsAreValid(int[][] array){
    return true;
puzzleIsValid(){
    //needs to return true if columns and rows return true
```

This is my question I have two true methods but they take a parameter(int[][] array){. How can I make puzzleIsValid without taking any parameters when columnsAreValid and rowsAreValid both return true. Thanks!

Comment: why wouldn't you want to pass rows and columns as parameters? that way  you could use your puzzleIsValid() method for any set of columns and rows.

Comment: What are the scopes of these methods?  Where are you getting your `int[][]` from?

Comment: I'm getting the int[][] from the main method, and I can't because this is for an assignment and I have done the bulk of the work I just cant figure out this presumably simple thing. There is the main method and then these methods that i have made.

Comment: why does this question get down voted?

Answer (score 0):

You store the outcome of `columnsAreValid(...)` and `rowsAreValid(...)` methods in an instance variable and then use the cumulative outcome to determine the return value of `puzzleIsValid()`

```
class Test
{
 private boolean flag;

 columnsAreValid(int[][] array)
 {
  flag = flag && //result of this method;
 }

 rowsAreValid(int[][] array)
 {
  flag = flag &&  //result of this method;
 }

 puzzleIsValid()
 {
  return flag;
 }
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry not sure what flag means

Comment: That is and instance variable storing the outcome of columnsAreValid(...) and rowsAreValid(...) CUMULATIVELY. This is required because you doesn't want to pass the int[][] array to  puzzleIsValid()